# weird error when popToRootViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have an Navigation-based app where i navigate trough some viewcontroller's.
At this moment I have 2 viewcontrollers. In the second viewcontroller, i have a condition that if it's true i pop to the first viewcontroller with popToRooViewController. When I do this the app return's to the rootController but in debugger console appears this :

> `**-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotation] called on <UIWindow: 0x3c04dd0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x3c05b90>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
>   Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.**`

I don't know why this is happen.

I create the project as a Navigation-Based application.In the mainWindow.xib it has the navigationController and as subview it has the navigationbar and the rootviewcontroller.

Then in the rootViewController I change to viewController instead of tableviewcontroller.
The second viewcontroller is also a viewcontroller.

Here is the code when i call the rootcontroller.

```
else if (emptyTasks == YES && returnAddTask == NO)
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // "Pushing the controller on the screen" 

    returnAddTask = YES;
}
```

Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: Hi, I have followed the steps in the question but don't get the error :( Can you provide more information about what is contained in the views/viewcontrollers that might be helpful? thanks, Sam

Comment: I got it! I solved my problem setting the animated:NO. It seems that it's a problem found in iPhone 3.0 device & simulator.

Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954982/uinavigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontroller-and-then-immediately-push-a-new-v

Thanks anyway!!:)

Comment: thanks to ideafactory.. i got same problem and solved by setting setting  animated:NO

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from the comments to the question itself. It is just put in an answer with the hope of someone up voting it and as such it can be moved away from the unanswered list.

By not using animation the error message does not appear.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but when I call `popToRootViewController` behind `UIScrollView`. It happen that UIScrollView steal self from its parent.

The solution is

```
[scrollview removeFromSuperview];
```

before `popToRootViewController`.