# UINavigationController presentModalViewController in rootviewcontroller didn't present with animations

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

I have a situation that need to judge  a invalid session and present the loing view controller.Now, after I get the message from server. I judge the statuscode . If it is a session error, I post a notification. The rootviewcontroller will handle the notification. Here is my Code in rootviewcontroller:

```
- (void)handleInvalidSessionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
UINavigationController * tmpController = self.navigationController;
[tmpController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
naviController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:naviController animated:YES];
```

}

Initially it did not work. I found this link [UINavigationController popToRootViewController, and then immediately push a new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954982/uinavigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontroller-and-then-immediately-push-a-new) , and change the Code:

```
 UINavigationController * tmpController = self.navigationController;
[tmpController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

It works, but no animations, do someone have a solution or suggestion....  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you don't simply push your viewController on your existing navigationController. Maybe like this:

```
      - (void)handleInvalidSessionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
      {
             LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];       
             [self.navigationController popViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
      }
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion....it is very simple, and it definitely a good solution....thanks, i will change the present style