# Handling Unbalanced calls to begin / end appearance when popping controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to add some error handling (to cope with loses of network connectivity when initializing my view models as well as elsewhere) by having it publish a message that is picked up by my view models that will then do a `ChangePresentation` with a `PresentationHint` that causes my presenter (derived from `MvxTouchViewPresenter`) to do this:

```
this.MasterNavigationController.PopToRootViewController(false);
```

This occasionally works, but a lot of the time it doesn't, getting stuck on whatever view it was currently on and I see the message `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyView: 0x...>`. I believe this is because sometimes the message is getting thrown before the view that was loading has had time to finish loading (the actual loading of data is asynchronous and fires up on another thread - hence the problem).

So my question is, is there a way to synchronize this so that instead of immediately popping to the root, it will finish what it's doing, then pop to the root? Or is there some better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not quite enough code in your question to work out what's happening. There are **lots** of other questions on StackOverflow containing that error message - it may be worth looking through them to see if there is a nice solution to your issue. e.g. [UINavigationController popToRootViewController, and then immediately push a new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954982/uinavigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontroller-and-then-immediately-push-a-new)

---

If you do want to detect 'finish loading' then on way to do this is to listen to the ViewDidAppear messages in the ViewControllers that are being shown. In mvx, this is easy to do as all ViewController's support a `ViewDidAppearCalled` event that you could easily hook up in your custom presenter:

```
    private readonly Queue<Action> _pendingActions = new Queue<Action>();
    private bool _isBusy;

    public override void Show(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.IMvxTouchView view)
    {
        if (_isBusy)
        {
            _pendingActions.Enqueue(() => Show(view));
            return;
        }

        _isBusy = true;
        var eventSource = view as IMvxEventSourceViewController;
        eventSource.ViewDidAppearCalled += OnViewAppeared;

        base.Show(view);
    }

    private void OnViewAppeared(object sender, MvxValueEventArgs<bool> mvxValueEventArgs)
    {
        _isBusy = false;
        var eventSource = sender as IMvxEventSourceViewController;
        eventSource.ViewDidAppearCalled -= OnViewAppeared;
        if (!_pendingActions.Any())
            return;

        var action = _pendingActions.Dequeue();
        action();
    }

    public override void ChangePresentation(Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if (_isBusy)
        {
            _pendingActions.Enqueue(() => ChangePresentation(hint));
            return;
        }

        base.ChangePresentation(hint);
    }
```

Note: this code requires 3.0.13 or later to work (there was a bug for `ViewDidAppear` in some view controllers in earlier versions)

If you are using a simple UINavigationController, another way to achieve a similar effect is to use the Delegate on that controller - see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think there might be some holes in my _pendingActions processing - e.g. how you cope with the queue getting two change presentations stuck in it - but I think the general approach should work :)

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I think that fixed that particular problem (after upgrading the nuget packages), but hasn't ultimately fixed my problem where calls to change presentation seem to be getting lost somehow. I'll have to dig deeper, but it's probably something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As @Stuart said, this approach has some holes. Basically, after this change my app stopped working at all :) Even "Close(this)" from the viewmodel itself is closing another view. Still patching the holes. If I get a solution, will update this question. Thanks for the idea