# Switching to an arbitrary view using `UINavigationController`

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iPhone app that uses a `UINavigationController` that is created as so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Create navigation controller and initialize it with the menu view controller.
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MenuViewController alloc] init]];
    navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;

    // Create main window and initialize it with navigation view controller.
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

From there things usually happen in a sequence similar to the following:

1. Push `SelectDifficultyViewController`
2. Push `GameViewController`
3. Push `GameOverViewController`
4. Pop to root (`MenuViewController`)

Instead of popping to the root in step 4, how would I go about switching to a new instance of `GameViewController`.

I currently have the following but it just returns me to the root:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[GameViewController alloc] initWithStuff:stuff] animated:NO];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly...why don't you just push another instance of `GameViewController` at step 4

Comment: Instead of popping and pushing? Because I figure it's probably better not to clutter up the stack with a large amount of view controllers. The idea is that there's a "play again" button so there's the possibility that the user could press it a large amount of times.

Comment: I see what you're saying...makes sense. How about just popping once at step 4 so you return to `GameViewController` from `GameOverViewController`

Comment: I need a different instance of `GameViewController`. The `init` method is more complicated, I just left out the details for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the line `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` will result in `self.navigationController` being nil, which is why the subsequent push to the navigationController does nothing. To fix this, store a local copy of the navigation controller and use that to push after popping to root. Credit for this answer comes from here:

[UINavigationController popToRootViewController, and then immediately push a new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954982/uinavigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontroller-and-then-immediately-push-a-new)

Answer (score 0):

mehinger's answer solved my problem, but I wanted to make it easier to use, so I made the following category.

**UINavigationController+PopAndPush.h**

```
@interface UINavigationController(PopAndPush)

- (void)popAndPushToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)popAndPushToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition;

@end
```

**UINavigationController+PopAndPush.m**

```
#import "UINavigationController+PopAndPush.h"

@implementation UINavigationController(PopAndPush)

- (void)popAndPushToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:animated];
}

- (void)popAndPushToViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withCustomTransition:(CustomViewAnimationTransition)transition {
    [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self pushViewController:controller withCustomTransition:transition subtype:nil];
}

@end
```