# Replace a Controller in Hierarchical Navigation Stack in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

Is there a way to replace your current controller in the navigation stack with WatchKit? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954982/uinavigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontroller-and-then-immediately-push-a-new) is how I'm doing it in my iPhone App, but I have not been able to find a way to duplicate this with WatchKit.

The closest alternative I'm looking into is just popping it and somehow having that controller know to push the new one. But I still haven't figured this out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a bool property in the first interface controller. When I call the second interface controller, I set this property to to true. Then, when I dismiss the second view controller, the first view controller's method `willActivate` is called. This is where I check the bool property and immediately pop the first interface controller if it is true.

This approach works but it has a disadvantage: The user sees the first view controller for a short while and then it disappears via an animation.

If anyone has a better idea, I would be very interested in it.

Comment: I was doing something like this at first, but I have an almost infinite nest that it will pop up through if the user goes a certain route. That's why I'd much rather replace it. If it were just one or even two stacks deep, I wouldn't mind this too much

Answer (score 0):

Problem: We want to replace interface controller *A* with interface controller *B*.

Here is one possible solution, which works well for me:

Let property *P* be a `bool` in the main (*M*) interface controller.

- Call interface controller *A* from *M*.
- To show *B* instead of *A*, set *P* to `true` and dismiss *A*.
- Method `willActivate` in *A* is executed. That's where you activate *B* if *P* is `true`. Before activating *B*, reset *P* to `false`.

Some comments:

- An interface controller is shown/activated by using the following Objective-C or Swift code:

  ```
  [self presentControllerWithName:@"InterfaceControllerXYZ" context:nil];

  self.presentControllerWithName("InterfaceControllerXYZ", context:nil)
  ```
- If you want to activate more than one interface controller from *M*, use an `int` instead of a `bool` to tell *M* which interface controller to activate.
- Of course, this approach not only works with the main interface controller but it could also be used with a controller deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: How do you "activate" another controller? Can you show some code here? The point of the swift tag was so that I could get a swift solution. Seems like this is just like your other answer

Comment: Sorry, good point. In this case the objective-c tag should indeed not be used. I'll add some code. This answer is indeed similar to my other answer. The difference is that interface controller `A` is now dismissed immediately. This is better (there is no longer the disadvantage that I mentioned in my other answer).

Comment: So this still isn't quite replacing it right? The main point I was thinking is the back button functionality wouldn't be working